# How to Search for a text in datagrid in WPF and highlight the searched text?

Tags: c#, wpf, search, datagrid

I'm searching the text in data grid view in WPF(XAML) and trying to highlight the matching string. In turn I want add the additional functionality to replace the given entered word with a different word. Same as we do in word Document.

I've tried this so far.

```
string SearchString = "";

public string HighlightText(string InputTxt)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
    {
        return InputTxt;
    } 
    else 
    {
        Regex ResultStr = default(Regex);
        ResultStr = new Regex(SearchString.Replace(" ", "|"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        return ResultStr.Replace(InputTxt, new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceWords));
    }
}

public string ReplaceWords(Match m)
{
    txtFindWord.SelectionStart = 0;
    txtFindWord.SelectionLength = txtFindWord.Text.Length;
}
```